# Solr sort on multivalue field produces Bytesref error in multi-shard env

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr8

Solr 8.11 (in SolrCloud mode) returns a 500 error when querying with sort parameter `sort=field("RECORD_DATE") asc`.

The error message is:

> class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @7f69d591)

`RECORD_DATE` is a multivalued field. I don't have problems when using a "simple" field such as `score` for sorting.

What is strange is that the error only occurs in a multi-shard environment. In a single-shard environment, there is no error!

Comment: Does the behavior change if you don't wrap it in `field`? There is generally no need to use a function query for plain sorting if you don't give a value after the `RECORD_DATE` parameter: " its simplest (single argument) form, this function can only be used on single valued fields, and can be called using the name of the field as a string" - you're expected to have a `min`/`max` qualifier behind it to select the corresponding value from the multivalued field (you'll need docvalues, and for efficiency you should resolve min/max when indexing)

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/function-queries.html#field-function

Comment: @MatsLindh unless I wrap `RECORD_DATE` in `field`, even the single-shard sort stops working – I get _java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException\n\tat org.apache.lucene.queries.function.FunctionValues.doubleVal(FunctionValues.java:50)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.queries.function.ValueSource$ValueSourceComparator.copy(ValueSource.java:417)_

In addition: `field(RECORD_DATE, min)` produces _sort param could not be parsed as a query, and is not a field that exists in the index_.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get `RECORD_DATE` sort work reliably. Apparently, it did not work reliably even with single shard Solr!
So, I switched the sort field from `RECORD_DATE` to `_version_`.

Benefits of using `_version_`:

1. single value field
2. always exists
3. sort order as desired - Solr document creation time